# ¿Qué quiere decir "hacerse de nuevas"?

Tags: expresiones, locuciones

Hace un tiempo encontré la frase:

> Cuando estos fiscales se lo contaron a Maza, él **se hizo de nuevas**, se mostró muy sorprendido y preocupado por la información (...)
>    <sub>[Fuente](http://www.eldiario.es/escolar/filtrador-Manuel-Moix_6_642245798.html)</sub>

En la noticia se habla de un tal Maza a quien le contaron algo y se mostró sorprendido de ello, pese a que realmente ya lo sabía.

El DLE lo recoge en:

> [**hacerse alguien de nuevas**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QhsYsNr)
>   1. loc. verb. Dar a entender con afectación y disimulo que no ha llegado a su noticia aquello que le dice otro, siendo cierto que ya lo sabía.

Asumo que [*nueva*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QhsYsNr) aquí usa su 5.ª acepción *Que sobreviene o se añade a algo que había antes*. Así y todo la expresión me resulta confusa en tanto en cuanto su "traducción" sería "hacerse de sobrevenido" y ese *hacerse de* + *de nuevas* es una construcción extraña.

¿Alguien podría clarificar su uso, así como validar si mi interpretación sobre la construcción de la expresión es correcta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo creo que es más sencillo. La interpretación que se le da puede ser la 2 ("que se percibe o experimenta por primera vez") o la 11 (sinónimo de "noticia"). Yo casi me decanto por la primera: así, "hacerse de nuevas" equivaldría a decir que haces como que las noticias que oyes son nuevas para ti (que las oyes por primera vez).

Veo además que la expresión es harto antigua, y se usa precisamente como indicas:

> *—¿Tan presto estás de vuelta? ¿Diste ya la saya a Chillón el sastre y el diamante al platero?
>
>   —¿Qué saya? ¿Qué diamante me has dado?
>
>   —No te hagas de nuevas ni burles de mí, que la saya y el diamante que me diste, te di.*
>
> Juan de Timoneda, "La comedia de los Menemnos. Traducción de Plauto", 1559 (España).

Expresiones similares podrían ser:

- [Hacerse el tonto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a1laMnE#7dV6QpF) / [sueco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YdyEKEV).
- Hacer como que no te has enterado.

Comment: Eso mismo estaba pensando yo, que era la 2ª acepción la que aplicaba en este caso. También está la expresión "coger de nuevas" cuando algo te pilla por sorpresa.